# How to clear array list of Model when i click back button from action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-recyclerview

I want to clear the array list or adapter when I click back button from action bar.Because I got problem when I pressed back button Items can routinely changed and display in Recycler View as well as some condition not working while display the Items.

Code:

```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // fragment = null;
    int id = item.getItemId();

    switch (id) {

        case android.R.id.home:
            Intent i=new Intent();
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            finish();
            return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one put your arraylist.clear() which you bind your adapter back button click in listview.

```
case android.R.id.home:
        yourarraylist.clear(); 
        finish();
        return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [clear()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#clear()) method of the `ArrayAdapter` class.
Hope, you're using `ArrayAdapter` class. If you are using `BaseAdapter` then wou will have to write your own function to clear the list, as the list is the hold by Your own class variable.

Comment: I used clear() when i am pressing back button still i am getting like that before what i get

Comment: Precise, what is going wrong right now, or paste updated code.
Because, how I understand Your code is whne pressing back arrow in Toolbar, new Intent is created, but never used, and the Activity is finished.

Comment: Even i am having problem from recyclerview taking wrong values